# Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made this simple script for a Google sheet, that runs when there is one of the conditions in the IF. It worked fine until a few days ago when it started to show the error "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id", crazy part is that it actually keeps working but only from row 70 ahead. No idea what's going on, I even deleted previous macros on the sheet to see if they were interfering.

```
function onEdit() {
var archivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var hojaorigen = archivo.getActiveSheet();
var nombreorigen= hojaorigen.getName();
var hojadestino = archivo.getSheetByName("NI/NAHO/DQ");
var celdactiva = hojaorigen.getActiveCell();
var filaactiva = celdactiva.getRow();
var colactiva = celdactiva.getColumn();
var valor = celdactiva.getValue();
var rangoorigen = hojaorigen.getRange(filaactiva, 1,1,21);
var rangodestino= hojadestino.getRange(hojadestino.getLastRow()+1,1)

Logger.log(filaactiva);
Logger.log(colactiva);
Logger.log(valor);

if(filaactiva >= 2 && colactiva == 16 && valor == "DISQUALIFIED"  && nombreorigen == "UPDATED Prototype lead claim") {
  rangoorigen.moveTo(rangodestino);
  hojaorigen.deleteRow(filaactiva);}
  else if (filaactiva>= 2 && colactiva == 16 && valor == "DO NOT CONTACT"  && nombreorigen == "UPDATED Prototype lead claim") {
  rangoorigen.moveTo(rangodestino);
  hojaorigen.deleteRow(filaactiva);
  }
  else if (filaactiva>= 2 && colactiva == 16 && valor == "NOT INTERESTED"  && nombreorigen == "UPDATED Prototype lead claim") {
  rangoorigen.moveTo(rangodestino);
  hojaorigen.deleteRow(filaactiva);
  }
  else if (filaactiva>= 2 && colactiva == 16 && valor == "INVALID NUMBER"  && nombreorigen == "UPDATED Prototype lead claim") {
  rangoorigen.moveTo(rangodestino);
  hojaorigen.deleteRow(filaactiva);
  }
  else if (filaactiva>= 2 && colactiva == 16 && valor == "WRONG NUMBER"  && nombreorigen == "UPDATED Prototype lead claim") {
  rangoorigen.moveTo(rangodestino);
  hojaorigen.deleteRow(filaactiva);
  }
}
```

The error that shows is the following, but as I said it only occurs when from rows 2  - 69, after that it works fine

[image]

Comment: activecell is a range not an integer [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell())

Comment: `filaactiva` and `hojadestino` are undefined

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The error message should be added textually (the file name and code line numer are missing). Also you should include the relevante details of your spreadsheet as what are the sheet names and how are you testing the function.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe what you're trying to achieve:

```
function oneEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const name = sh.getName();
  if (sh.getName() == "UPDATED Prototype lead claim" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 16) {
    if (e.value == "DISQUALIFIED" || e.value == "DO NOT CONTACT" || e.value == "WRONG NUMBER" || e.value == "NOT INTERESTED" || e.value == "INVALID NUMBER") {
      e.range.moveTo(e.source.geetSheetByName("NI/NAHO/DQ"));
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart)
    }
  }
}
```

It's hard to say for sure because you have two undefined variable as I said in my comments and getActiveCell() returns and range not an integer or row as I suspect  you wanted.  Also please note you cannot run functions like this from the script editor unless you pass them the event object.

Comment: Sorry. My original function was in spanish and clearly i made a lot of mistakes translating

Comment: Here is the original funtion: